# How would you store categories and sub categories in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

How would i design a mongodb schema to store Categories and Sub-Categories.
I need an id for each category/subcategory and a way to determine the nesting of sub categories under each category.

Also, i should be able to associate a Poll question with the category/subcategory.